# $\sigma$ additivity

Tags: probability, measure-theory

I' m trying to understand the difference between an algebra and a $\sigma$-algebra in the context of probability.

I found that the difference is that an algebra is closed under finite countable unions of events and a $\sigma$-algebra under infinite countable unions, $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}A_i$.

I searched the forum and I found and example of a $\sigma$-algebra:

[Example of $\sigma$-algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/659988/example-of-sigma-algebra)

"$X = \{a, b, c, d\}$ a possible sigma algebra on $X$ is $Σ = \{∅, \{a, b\}, \{c, d\}, \{a, b, c, d\}\}$

I don't understand why this is a $\sigma$-algebra, as it is a finite countable union, not an infinite countable one.

Comment: Why do you think a $\sigma$ algebra needs to be infinite?

Comment: Because if not, it is an algebra. Thats what the definition says. It is a $\sigma$-algebra when the union is infinite.

Comment: That's not correct. :)

Comment: Every algebra on a finite set is automatically a $\sigma$-algebra, because any countable union is in the algebra (since all possible countable unions are finite).

Comment: There's something I don't grasp. Countable does not mean infinite? I don't understand when you say that "any countable union is in the algebra" (since all possible countable unions are finite) It it is a countable union,(infinite) it can' be finite. I'm confused here.

Comment: Countable does NOT mean infinite. Countable means at most the cardinality of $\Bbb{N}$

Comment: Whenever I read a book with the word countable, there is this summation $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}$, implying infinite countable.

Comment: Sometimes, the set $A$ is countable if $|A| = |\mathbb{N}|$, and sometimes if $|A|\leq |\mathbb{N}|$. I have seen both definitions.

Comment: @Antoine. How can you tell when  |A|=|N| and |A|<=|N|?

Comment: @user1952009. So a $\sigma$-algebra is ALWAYS closed under countablt infinite operations, and never under finite operations?!

Comment: Do you agree with that : *a $\sigma$-algebra is a set algebra (a boolean algebra over a set) closed under countably infinite operations. A boolean algebra is a algebra over the field with $2$ elements $\mathbb{F}_2$, except that we don't look at the addition (xor) but instead at the union ($\lor$, $\cup$), the multiplication being $\land,\cap$*

Comment: $|A| = |\mathbb{N}| \Leftrightarrow$ there is a bijection between $A$ and $\mathbb{N}$, and $|A| \leq |\mathbb{N}| \Leftrightarrow$ there is a injection FROM $A$ TO $\mathbb{N}$

Comment: @match6 any $\sigma$-algebra, set algebra, boolean algegra or algebra over a field have to be closed under finite operations..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A $\sigma$ algebra on a set $S$ is a collection $\sigma\subseteq 2^S$ that satisfies:

1) $\emptyset, S\in \sigma$

2) If $X\in \sigma$ then $X^c\in \sigma$

3) If $\{X_n\}_{n\in\Bbb{N}}$ are sets where $X_n\in \sigma$ then $\cup_{n\in\Bbb{N}} X_n\in \sigma$.

The $X_n$ do not need to be distinct. In particular if you have $X_1,...,X_k$ is some collection of sets, then $X_n\cup...\cup X_k\cup \emptyset\cup \emptyset\cup...\in \sigma$

Comment: "Countable does NOT mean infinite. Countable means at most the cardinality of N" . Do you mean that countable can be finite or infinite? So if the definition of $\sigma$-algebra is a countable union, then a $\sigma-algebra$, that is closed under a countable union, the summation for the $\sigma$-algebra can be $\sum_{i=1}^{n}$, which is countable and not infinite.

Comment: @match6 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Countable_set "In mathematics, a countable set is a set with the same cardinality (number of elements) as some subset of the set of natural numbers." Countable means finite or countably infinite. I'm not sure where you're getting a summation from, the definition of a $\sigma$ algebra doesn't include anything about summation (although it usually is mentioned in the context of a measure which does include summation).

Comment: So if I got it right, a sigma-algebra of events is closed under countable union, which can be finite countable (for instance when the power set is finite) or infinite countable. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Note that the sets $A_i$ do not need to be different, for example $\sum_{i = 1}^\infty \emptyset \in \Sigma$.

Every $\sigma$-algebra $\Sigma$ is also an algebra: take arbitrary $n$ and sets $A_i$, $1\leq i \leq n$. Define $A_i = \emptyset$ for $i > n$. Then

$$\sum_{i = 1}^n A_i = \sum_{i = 1}^\infty A_i \in \Sigma\text{,}$$
since $\sigma$-algebras are closed under countably infinite sums.

In your case, let $B = \{a, b\}$, $C = \{c, d\}$ and $D = \{a,b,c,d\}$. Take arbitrary sum $\sum_i A_i$. Then

$$\sum_{i= 1}^\infty A_i = \sum_{i:\;A_i = \emptyset} A_i + \sum_{i:\;A_i = B} A_i +\sum_{i:\;A_i = C} A_i + \sum_{i:\;A_i = D} A_i\text{,}$$
and, for example, the second sum on RHS can be substituted by $B$ if there is $i$, such that $A_i = B$, and by $\emptyset$ otherwise. Similarly for the other sums. Hence, in your case, every infinite union can be written as a finite union of no more than $4$ sets.

Answer (score 0):

This information is taken from my textbook at the beginning of Continuous Distributions:

"In the continuous case, insisting that every subset of $\Omega$ have a well-defined probability will lead to contradictions, so we must shrink $\mathscr F$ from the power set of $\Omega$ to a smaller collection of subsets. But we want to keep the good properties of a probability measure, including its good behavior under intersections and unions.
So while the collection of $\mathscr F$ of possible events might no longer be the entire power set of $\Omega$, it should be closed under the operations of:

1. Complement,
2. Countable Unions
3. Countable intersections.

This is what is denoted as a $\sigma$-algebra."

Using a $\sigma$-algebra essentially allows us to keep things such as Conditional Probability like Bayes' Formula, the definition of independence, and other probability equations in continuous probability.

Examples of $\sigma$-algebras include:

$\mathscr F = \{\emptyset, \Omega\}$

$\mathscr F = \{\emptyset, A, A^c,\Omega\}$

$\mathscr F = 2^\Omega$