# Example of a $\sigma$-algebra in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

In a measure theory course we have just learned about $\sigma$-algebras and Borel sets. We defined a $\sigma$-algebra as a collection $S$ of sets which satisfies the following:

1. $S$ is closed under complementation of sets.
2. $S$ is closed under countable union.

Now, I'm wondering what one such collection might look like or be defined as in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and hopefully someone can help me out here.

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/659988/example-of-sigma-algebra) and its answers helped to ground my understanding a bit more but I'm still looking for more. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: The smallest sigma algebra in $\Bbb R^n$ is $\{\emptyset , \Bbb R^n\}$

Comment: Any set $A$ has the trivial $\sigma$-algebras $S=\{ \emptyset,A \}$ and $S=\mathcal{P}(A)$ where $\mathcal{P}$ is the power set. Most of the time we work with $\sigma$-algebras between these extremes; the main two in $\mathbb{R}^n$ are the collection of Borel sets and the collection of Lebesgue measurable sets.

Answer (score 2):

One example of a $\sigma$-algebra in $\mathbb{R}^n$  is the [Borel $\sigma$-algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel_set), defined as the smallest $\sigma$-algebra that contains all the open sets in $\mathbb{R}^n$. This is a basic and important example of a $\sigma$-algebra that you should know about. If you have not yet read about how a $\sigma$-algebra is *generated* from any arbitrary subset of the power set, then do so and come back to this example.

Another closely related example is the $\sigma$-algebra of [Lebesgue measurable sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_measure). It is the [*completion*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_measure) of the Borel $\sigma$-algebra. If you haven't seen these ideas in your course yet, then you will be seeing them quite soon. Complete measures are also quite important.

In the question that you've linked, the two trivial examples of $\sigma$-algebras are also mentioned: namely the power set $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and the collection $\{ \emptyset, \mathbb{R}^n \}$.

---

Additionally, one small nitpick. You must define a $\sigma$-algebra in a set $X$ to be a collection of sets that satisfies the two conditions you mentioned, *and also has $X$ as a member.* Don't forget the last condition.

Comment: Your nitpick is correct and it is equivalent to $S\ne \emptyset$. For if $y\in S$ then $y^c=X\backslash y \in S$ so $X=y\cup y^c\in S. $

Comment: To the proposer: Let $A\subset X$. Let $F$ be  the set of all $\sigma$-algebras on $X$ that have $A$ as a subset. Then $F$ is not empty because the power-set $ P(X)\in F.$ It is an easy exercise to show that the common intersection  $\cap F$ of all the members of $F$ is also a member of $F.$ The set $\cap F$ is called the $\sigma$-algebra on $X$ generated by $A.$  It is the  $\subset$-smallest  $\sigma$-algebra on $X$ that has $A$ as a subset. That is, any $\sigma$-algebra on $X$ that has $A$ as a subset  also has  $\cap F$ as a subset.